# Android Studio can not see MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is a new project created by the android studio. I did not change anything in this project, but in the activity_main.xml file, MainActivity.java can not find, and there is a MainActivity.java file in this project. How I can make this run. (MainActivity.java see activity_main.xml as related )
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share your MainActivity.java file? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can remove the tools:context if not working it won't affect major things like it's just for giving theme to your layout while coding in xml but theme will work when you run your app.

Comment: you can add full package name in context `context="com.example.myapplication.MianActivity"`

Comment: Adding context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" is not working. Removing the tools from the file didn't work too.

Comment: Select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button. Clean and rebuild your project. @ozan33.java

Comment: I renamed it to Main.java and it was fine (i think some issue with android studio and kotlin's plugin)

Answer (score 0):

If you really haven't made any changes prior to this happening, try cleaning and rebuilding the project in the build tab. If it doesn't work, try restarting Android studio.

Comment: No, it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's not get accourate path of your package. You can Use
`com.example.myapplication.MainActivity` that times it's work properly.

**OR**

Invalid caches/restart android studio.

Comment: Remove  `.ManiActivity` after that write `.` and press Clt + space then IDEA give you suggestion.

Comment: From activity_main IDEA did not give me any suggestion but from AndroidManifest it gave me MainActivity as a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you are writing it wrong instead of ".MainActivity" write it as "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity", sometimes android studio does not give us any hint or suggestion while writing or replacing ".MainActivity", but when you try to write from the start it will surely give you suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Add your activity to `AndroidManifest.xml` under `<application>`

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
      <!-- MAIN represents that it is the Main Activity-->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <!-- Launcher Denotes that it will be the first launching activity-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: My AndroidManifest is same as your post.(under <application>)